# return undefined when adding array index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to translate all alphabets in a message to p alphabet(s) in the sequence. for example: Translate("bbcd", 2) will return "ddef".  I am stuck at the array part where alphabets[j+p] returns undefined.  If I do alphabets[j-p], it will work.

Here is my code:

```
function Translate(Message, p) {
var alphabets = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
var message_array = Message.split('');
for(var i in message_array){
    for(var j in alphabets){
        if(message_array[i]==alphabets[j]){
            message_array[i]=alphabets[j+p];//returns undefined
        }
    }
}
return message_array;
}
console.log(Translate("bbcd", 2));
```

Comment: what if the `Message` has `y` or `z` in it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `j+p` which is doing a string concatenation, `typeof j` will return `string` as you are reading the array index using `for...in`

```js
function Translate(message, p) {
  var alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

  return message.split('').map(function(c) {
    var idx = alphabets.indexOf(c);
    return idx == -1 ? c : alphabets[(idx + p) % alphabets.length]
  });

}

var value = Translate("azpq", 2);
result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(value);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`alphabets[j+p];` returns undefined for `j == 26` that it will reach for the inner loop iteration.

use `indexOf` method of array and change your loop structure to

```
for(var i in message_array)
{ 
   var index = alphabets.indexOf( message_array[ i ] );
   message_array[ i ] = alphabets[ index + 2 ];
}
```

This also will reach 'undefined' if your `Message` has a `y` or `z` in it.

so, you might want to cycle it back to the beginning

```
for(var i in message_array)
{ 
   var index = alphabets.indexOf( message_array[ i ] );
   message_array[ i ] = alphabets[ (index + 2) % alphabets.length ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Translate(Message, p) {
            var alphabets = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
            var messageLength = Message.length;
            var returnMessage = '';

            for(var i=0; i< messageLength; i++) {
                var myChar = Message.charAt(i);
                var placeChar = alphabets.indexOf(myChar);

                myChar = alphabets[placeChar + p];

                returnMessage += myChar;
            }

            return returnMessage;
        }

        console.log(Translate("bbcd", 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break once the value is found. Otherwise the inner loop will find a match again on the coming cycles.

```js
function Translate(Message, p) {
  var alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
  var message_array = Message.split('');
  for (var i in message_array) {
    for (var j in alphabets) {
      if (message_array[i] == alphabets[j]) {
        console.log(alphabets[parseInt(j) + parseInt(p)])
        message_array[i] = alphabets[parseInt(j) + parseInt(p)]; //returns undefined
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return message_array;
}
alert(Translate("bbcd", 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that j+p is never bigger than the length of alphabets. This will result in a "out of bounds" error. e.g. p = 30.

A fix is to just check the length compared to p and returns something that is defined.

```
message_array[i] = (j+p > alphabets.length) ? alphabets[j+p] : alphabets[j]; // returns element at j if out of bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion works with an alphabet string instead of an array.

You can access a string like an array for a single character. For the lookup i suggest to use `indexOf()`, a method availabele at string objects [`String#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) as well as array objects [`Array#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Both methods returns the position of the found item/string/character or `-1` if not found.

For the result I took an empty string and concatinated it with the new character.

For the correct range of the index, while adding some value, the method of choice is to use the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()). It returns the reminder of a division by the second number. Here it is the length of the `alphabet` string.

```js
function translate(message, p) {
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        i, pos, result = '';
    for (i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        pos = alphabet.indexOf(message[i]);
        result += alphabet[(pos + p) % alphabet.length];
    }
    return result;
}

document.write(translate("bbcd", 2));
```